# Magento2 Add Custom Sort By Option ( Special Price Low - High)

Tags: magento2, filter, product-collection, category-products, sort-by-options

I Want to Add New Sort By  Option Like (Special Price From Low To High).
Does any one know how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create plugins

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="custom_custom_block_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="custom_catalog_model_config" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**Step 2:** Create **Config.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    $options
    ) {

        $options['low_to_high'] = __('Price - Low To High');
        $options['high_to_low'] = __('Price - High To Low');
        return $options;

    }
    
}
```

**Step 3:** Create **Toolbar.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar
{
  
    /**
    * Plugin
    *
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject
    * @param \Closure $proceed
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
    */
    public function aroundSetCollection(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $collection
    ) {
    $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
    $result = $proceed($collection);

    if ($currentOrder) {
        if ($currentOrder == 'high_to_low') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('special_price', 'desc');
        } elseif ($currentOrder == 'low_to_high') {
            $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('special_price', 'asc');
        }
    }

    return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks For your answer  but i want  only special  price products

Comment: then you have to filter product collection to show only that products which contacting special price.

Comment: $subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['neq' => '']); please keep in mind "special price from" and  "special price to" date

Comment: $subject->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilte() this function is working okay for single category only ,if i use sort by in another categories than it returns empty ccollection